# How do you capture environmental or camera settings in Machine Learning CNN architectures?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I've been looking at computer vision problems. The CNN works exclusively with the image, and other factors like camera settings (f stop, ISO, etc) or environmental factors aren't directly taken into account. I can imagine a scenario where lighting conditions would factor in how an object gets "seen" (in a mobile platform application, for example).

Is there a way to explicitly have those factors taken into account within the NN architecture, or are they just implied via the dataset images used? How do you feed it into the NN since the input is just an image? It wouldn't make sense to just add another row and populate that with parameters; I would imagine the convolution would scramble the effects.

An example: say you are looking for a cylinder. In one image, you would be looking for a rectangle like object since you are viewing the cylinder sideways. In another view, you would be looking for a circle because you are looking at the tip.

Comment: just feed it in as another input... assuming you can feed that in during inference as well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz,  how would you go about doing that? The CNN field would convolve  the pixel that represents the parameter. That doesn't seem the right way to process the information.

Comment: You could broadcast it and add as a channel, or add it after the convolutional layers, before a dense layer.

Comment: DNNs don't have to be uniform linear constructs. DNNs can be graphs. feed image data through convolution layers. feed other data into the network at any point (even later). split and merge however you like. you should read a few more papers on what kinds of networks people build to solve their problems, just for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  for taking a look at my question. Looking further into it, I find that the type of problem is called "mixed data" ingestion and found a link to a tutorial [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/).